# Detect colors using camara in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera, augmented-reality, color-detection

I'm trying to develop an aplication in Android Studio.
This aplication should get the exactly color of one pixel touched in the camara.
I don't find anywhere how to do this, i don't even know what to put in xml and how to handle the results given.
Thank you very much for your time.